# Proving the Expectation is Finite

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose for some $ p > 0 $ $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^p P(|X| > n) = 0 $$

Show that for all $r < p , \; E(|X|^r) < \infty $

I'm not sure how to make use of this fact to prove the expectation is finite. Even when I split the expectation into cases I cant find a way to use the condition. Also, I'm not even sure why this strictly requires $r < p$ either.

Comment: You might need the fact that $E(|X|) = \int_{0}^\infty P(|X|\geq t)dt$.

Comment: Use $E(|X|^r)=\int_0^{\infty}r|X|^{r-1}P(|X|>t)\,dt$

Comment: You can only show the above for  $r\geq 0$ otherwise it doesn't have to hold (for example in case $P(X=0)>0$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $E(|X|) = \int_{0}^\infty P(|X|\geq t)dt$ by Fubini's theorem( $E|X|= E( \int_0^\infty 1_{\{X\geq t\}}dt)$). Using this, we can relate expectation to $P(|X|\geq t)$.

Since $\int_{0}^\infty P(|X|^r\geq t)dt\leq 1+ \int_{1}^\infty P(|X|\geq t^\frac{1}{r}) dt=1+\int_{1} ^\infty P(X|\geq y) ry^{r-1} dy$ $ \leq 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n} ^{n+1} P(X|\geq y) ry^{r-1} dy\leq 1+ 2r\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X|\geq n)(n+1)^{r-1} $,

and $\lim n^p P(|X|>n ) = 0 $ implies that $P(|X|>n) \leq C_1 n^{-p}$ for some constant $C_1$, we know $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X|\geq n)(n+1)^{r-1}$ would be less than $C_2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1+p-r}}$ for some $C_2$ and the rest should be obvious.

Comment: Thanks ! .I think I was missing the fact that we can change the integral into a sum  of integrals like that. Haven't done it in class yet. Is it monotone convergence that allows you to do that?

Comment: For $\int_{1}^\infty P(|X|\geq y)ry^{r-1}dy \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n}^{n+1} ...$, I just split $[1,\infty)$ to $[n,n+1)$. $\sum \int_n^{n+1} ... \leq 2r \sum P(|X|\geq n )(n+1)^{r-1}$, you just try to find a maximum of $P(|X|\geq y)r y^{r-1}$ in the interval $[n,n+1]$.